# OptimisticConcurrencyException when updating child entities

Tags: entity-framework-4

**NOTE: This is based on my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263952/optimisticconcurrencyexception-with-entity-framework-on-an-update-affects-0-rows) but this is subtly different. I have resolved the issue on the other question, this is specifically regarding child entities.**

I have a data-structure such that:

SecurityPolicy 1<---* SecurityPolicyRule

Therefore, a SecurityPolicy can have 0, one or many SecurityPolicyRules.

I am using Julie Lerman's Entity Framework book to implement some degree of concurrency checking, TDD and POCO support.

I understand that each table should have a rowversion/timestamp field, which is marked as ConcurrencyMode==Fixed.

I have decided to implement the CUD in Stored Procedures. My UPDATE Sproc is as follows:

```
create PROCEDURE dbo.sp_M2_Core_UpdateSecurityPolicy
    @ID int,
    @Name nvarchar(256),
    @Comment nvarchar(max)=null,
    @timestamp timestamp
AS

declare @nameExists nvarchar(256)

    select @nameExists= [Name] from M2_Core_SecurityPolicy where [Name]=@Name and [ID]<>@id
    if (not @nameExists is null)
    begin
        raiserror (N'Name is already in use: %s',
        11,
        1,
        @Name)
    end
    else
    begin
        update M2_Core_SecurityPolicy
            set [Name]=@Name,
                [Comment]=@Comment
                where id=@id and [timestamp]=@timestamp
        IF @@ROWCOUNT>0
            SELECT [Timestamp] AS newTimeStamp FROM M2_Core_SecurityPolicy WHERE id=@id
    end

go

create PROCEDURE dbo.sp_M2_Core_UpdateSecurityPolicyRule    
    (
    @id int,
    @RoleName nvarchar(256),
    @Rank int,
    @CanReadExecute bit=null,
    @CanWrite bit=null,
    @CanDelete bit=null,
    @CanExport bit=null,
    @Timestamp timestamp
    )

AS

    declare @roleExists nvarchar(256)
    declare @securityPolicyID int

    select @roleExists= [RoleName] from vw_aspnet_Roles where [RoleName]=@RoleName
    if (@roleExists is null)
    begin
        raiserror (N'Role is not defined: %s',
        11,
        1,
        @roleName)
    end
    else
    begin
        select @securityPolicyID=[SecurityPolicyID] from M2_Core_SecurityPolicyRule where [id]=@id

        -- move all other rules up in priority
        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM M2_Core_SecurityPolicyRule WHERE [ID]<>@ID AND [SecurityPolicyID]=@SecurityPolicyID AND [Rank]=@Rank) > 0 
        BEGIN
            UPDATE M2_Core_SecurityPolicyRule
                SET [Rank]=[Rank]+1
                WHERE [Rank] >= @rank
                    AND [SecurityPolicyID]=@SecurityPolicyID
                    AND [ID]<>@ID
        END

        update M2_Core_SecurityPolicyRule
            set [RoleName]=@RoleName,
                [Rank]=@Rank,
                [CanReadExecute]=@CanReadExecute,
                [CanWrite]=@CanWrite,
                [CanDelete]=@CanDelete,
                [CanExport]=@CanExport              
                where id=@id and [timestamp]=@timestamp
        IF @@ROWCOUNT>0
            SELECT [Timestamp] AS newTimeStamp FROM M2_Core_SecurityPolicyRule WHERE id=@id

    end

    RETURN

go
```

I am testing this using some code that:

1. Creates a Security Policy
2. Adds a created Security Policy Rule to the Security Policy
3. Adds the Security Policy
4. Saves the updates
5. Adds 1 to the Rank of the Security Policy Rule
6. Saves the updates

The test is below:

```
[TestMethod()]
        public void AddWithSecurityPolicyRuleChangeRankTest()
        {
            ICoreContext coreContext = new CoreEntities(_coreDbConnectionString);
            CoreUnitOfWork coreUnitOfWork = new CoreUnitOfWork(coreContext);
            SecurityPolicyRepository target = new SecurityPolicyRepository(coreUnitOfWork);
            int originalCount = coreContext.SecurityPolicies.Count();
            string securityPolicyName = "addwithsecuritypolicyrulechangeruletest";
            int originalRank = 1;
            SecurityPolicy entity = new SecurityPolicy()
            {
                Comment = null,
                Name = securityPolicyName,
                SecurityPolicyRules = new FixUpCollection<SecurityPolicyRule>()
            };
            entity.SecurityPolicyRules.Add(
                new SecurityPolicyRule()
                {
                    CanDelete = null,
                    CanExport = null,
                    CanReadExecute = null,
                    CanWrite = null,
                    Rank = originalRank,
                    RoleName = "User"
                });
            target.Add(entity);
            coreUnitOfWork.Save();

            entity.SecurityPolicyRules[0].Rank=originalRank+1;
            coreUnitOfWork.Save(); // <-- exception thrown here
            SecurityPolicy savedSecurityPolicy = target.GetAll().Single(q => q.Name.Equals(securityPolicyName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
            Assert.AreEqual(originalRank+1,savedSecurityPolicy.SecurityPolicyRules[0].Rank);
        }
```

However, when I run this, it throws an exception at the highlighted line. The exception is:

> System.Data.OptimisticConcurrencyException
>   was unhandled by user code
>   Message=Store update, insert, or
>   delete statement affected an
>   unexpected number of rows (0).
>   Entities may have been modified or
>   deleted since entities were loaded.
>   Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.
>   Source=System.Data.Entity
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ValidateRowsAffected(Int64
>   rowsAffected, UpdateCommand source)
>          at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager
>   stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
>          at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager
>   entityCache)
>          at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions
>   options)
>          at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges()
>          at MIGTurbo2.Core.Data.CoreEntities.Save()
>   in
>   D:\dev\migturbo2.0\MIGTurbo2.Core\Data\Core.Context.cs:line
>   92
>          at MIGTurbo2.Repositories.CoreUnitOfWork.Save()
>   in
>   D:\dev\migturbo2.0\MIGTurbo2.Repositories\CoreUnitOfWork.cs:line
>   26
>          at MIGTurbo2.Core.Tests.IntegrationTests.SecurityPolicyRepositoryTest.AddWithSecurityPolicyRuleChangeRankTest()
>   in
>   D:\dev\migturbo2.0\MIGTurbo2.Core.Tests\IntegrationTests\SecurityPolicyRepositoryTest.cs:line
>   524   InnerException:

And sure enough, no data has changed. ie. The [Rank] is still 1 from the first update (therefore, the INSERT). However, running it through SQL Profiler and Ayende's EF Profiler, no calls to the database are even made to make the UPDATE. So the relevance of the timestamp/rowversion is surely ... irrelevant?

What could be causing this? I don't want to have to Refresh the DB on every Save! This ONLY happens when updating the child entity. Changing the parent SecurityPolicy works fine.

**Update 1:**

When running the INSERT code, the SecurityPolicyRule is created fine. This issue is specific to UPDATE and DELETE operations.

**Update 2:**

I've figured out that if I set the state of the entity, it does get submitted to the database. The EF is obvioulsy picking up my State property (using the mechanism explained in Julie's book) fine now. So my test code now looks like this when updating the item:

```
entity.SecurityPolicyRules[0].Rank=originalRank+1;;
entity.SecurityPolicyRules[0].State = IWW.Elements.State.Modified;
```

However, despite the call and parameters sent to the database being present and correct, it is still not working. Interestingly, as shown in the screenie below, the last line is displayed AFTER the exception. Though I'm sure that this is only down to the Entity Framework Profile "flushing" its monitors.

Is the Stored Procedure of the child entity returning correct data?

[image: Result from Ayende's Entity Framework Profiler]